# Navigation to a custom webpart using ID in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, office-365-developer

I have created a custom app for texts heading and add options for adding id to the DOM element or the given div.

[image]

Then add custom links in the page using the id of DOM eg:

> sites/OperationsPeople#M

Some time this anchor tag navigates successfully but some time it doesn't work in the SharePoint page.

Comment: Try creating link in this format: `sites/OperationsPeople/SitePages/<HomePage>.aspx#M`. Replace `<HomePage>` with the name of home page of site.

Comment: I tried but didn't worked